# error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
void Partition(int*Data,int low, int high, int& pivotpoint, int& CompareCount)
{
    int i ,j;
    // low is pivot ...

    int pivotitem = Data[low];
    j= low;
    for(i=low+1; i<=high;i++)
    {
        //data<pivot -> to low position
        if(Data[i] <pivotitem)
        {
            j++;
            int k = Data[i];
            Data[i] = Data[j];
            Data[j] = k;
        }
        CompareCount++;
    }
    //move pivot ,pivot position
    pivotpoint = j;
    int k = Data[j];
    Data[j]=Data[low];
    Data[low] = k;
}
```

here

I think the use of '&' is right.

But it didn't compile.

this is error and warning

> error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
>   warning: no newline at end of file

I don't know why this is happen~

Comment: References are a C++ thing, you can't use them in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, there is no call by reference, only call by value. Remove `&` and place `*`.

```
void Partition(int *Data, int low, int high, int *pivotpoint, int *CompareCount){...}
```

Comment: ...and adjust the calls of `Partition()` accordingly, as well as the use of those parameters within `Partition()`. References take variables and are referenced as-is, pointers take **addresses* of variables and are referenced as `*pointer`. Pointers are not drop-in replacements for references. This answer, as it stands, goes only half-way, if that far.

Comment: so i change this one. but it didn't work.                                ' warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast'

Comment: @user3450300: Probably the point where you should cease trial & error, and instead grab your favourite C book and read up on the proper use of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Pass by reference, `int&`, is pure C++ and not available in C.